# Shutdown Hook Corda integration testing

Tags: corda

I have the following [Corda service](https://github.com/altfatterz/learning-corda/blob/master/workflows/iou-workflow/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flows/IOUFlow.kt). It starts up a Jetty Server

```
@CordaService
class IOUService(private val serviceHub: AppServiceHub): SingletonSerializeAsToken() {

    init {
        val port = serviceHub.myInfo.addresses.first().port - 1002
        log.println("IOUService init was called...")
        log.println("Port: $port")

        val jettyServer = JettyServer()
        jettyServer.start(port)
    }
}
```

My problem is how to release the stared Jetty port when running integration tests. Here are two example test (basically the same test twice to illustrate the problem):

```
    @Test
    fun `node test`() = withDriver {
        val (partyAHandle, partyBHandle) = startNodes(bankA, bankB)
        assertEquals(bankB.name, partyAHandle.resolveName(bankB.name))
        assertEquals(bankA.name, partyBHandle.resolveName(bankA.name))
    }

    @Test
    fun `node test2`() = withDriver {
        val (partyAHandle, partyBHandle) = startNodes(bankA, bankB)
        assertEquals(bankB.name, partyAHandle.resolveName(bankB.name))
        assertEquals(bankA.name, partyBHandle.resolveName(bankA.name))
    }
```

The first test will start up 3 nodes: one notary, BankA and BankB nodes with the following details:

```
Notary:
Advertised P2P messaging addresses      : localhost:10000
RPC connection address                  : localhost:10001
RPC admin connection address            : localhost:10002
Jetty Port: 8998

BankA:
Advertised P2P messaging addresses      : localhost:10004
RPC connection address                  : localhost:10005
RPC admin connection address            : localhost:10006
Jetty Port: 9002

BankB:
Advertised P2P messaging addresses      : localhost:10008
RPC connection address                  : localhost:10009
RPC admin connection address            : localhost:10010
Jetty Port: 9006
```

Unfortunately the second test will fails since the Jetty ports are still bound:

```
[ERROR] 14:22:04,825 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.Node.installCordaServices - Corda service com.example.flows.IOUService failed to instantiate. Reason was: Address already in use [errorCode=1pryyp4, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.1/1pryyp4]
 java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9006
```

How to register a shutdown hook during integration testing in order to shut down the Jetty servers?

The example code can be found here:

https://github.com/altfatterz/learning-corda

Answer (score 0):

A proper lifecycle for corda services is currently being looked at. Hopefully, you can do this in the future.

For now, there is not a simple way to do this from within the node.